# manage more than one Elasticsearch container with docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

i need use more than elasticsearch node in the same machine.but whene i add the second elasticsearch service in docker-compose.yml. all elasticsearch services crach.
my sample yml file :

```
version: "2"
services:
    elasticsearch_master:
        image: elasticsearch:latest
        command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=workagram -Des.node.master=true -Des.node.data=false"
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"
            - 9300
    elasticsearch1:
        image: elasticsearch:latest
        command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name=workagram -Des.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch_master"
        links:
            - elasticsearch_master
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768556/docker-swarm-cluster-and-elasticsearch-using-constraints-to-bind-a-service-to-a Take a look at this. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768556/docker-swarm-cluster-and-elasticsearch-using-constraints-to-bind-a-service-to-a Take a look at this. Let me know if you have questions.