# Docker swarm cluster and elasticsearch, using constraints to bind a service to a specific node

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose, elastic-stack

i was hoping someone here might be able to give me some input with a problem i'm having.

I have a Docker swarm cluster with 3 nodes and want to run the ELK stack but i am not sure how to store my data.

```
version: '3'
services:
  master01:
    image: elasticsearch:5.2.2
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - es
    volumes:
      - /es/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    command: >
      elasticsearch
      -E network.host=_eth0_
      -E node.master=true
      -E discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es_master01,es_master02,es_master03
      -E discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=3
      -E cluster.name=ElasticCluster
      -E node.name=es_master01
      -E transport.tcp.port=9300
      -E http.port=9200
      -E node.max_local_storage_nodes=3
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  master02:
    image: elasticsearch:5.2.2
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
      - 9301:9300
    networks:
      - es
    volumes:
      - /es/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    command: >
      elasticsearch
      -E network.host=_eth0_
      -E node.master=true
      -E discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es_master01,es_master02,es_master03
      -E discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=3
      -E cluster.name=ElasticCluster
      -E node.name=es_master02
      -E transport.tcp.port=9300
      -E http.port=9200
      -E node.max_local_storage_nodes=3
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  master03:
    image: elasticsearch:5.2.2
    ports:
      - 9202:9200
      - 9302:9300
    networks:
      - es
    volumes:
      - /es/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    command: >
      elasticsearch
      -E network.host=_eth0_
      -E node.master=true
      -E discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es_master01,es_master02,es_master03
      -E discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=3
      -E cluster.name=ElasticCluster
      -E node.name=es_master03
      -E transport.tcp.port=9300
      -E http.port=9200
      -E node.max_local_storage_nodes=3
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  logstash:
    image: logstash:5.2.2
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - es
    command: >
      logstash -e 'input { tcp { port => 5000 } } output { elasticsearch { hosts => "master01:9200" } }'
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  kibana:
    image: kibana:5.2.2
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: "kibana"
      SERVER_HOST: "0"
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://elastic:changeme@master01:9200"
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: "elastic"
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: "changeme"
      XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED: "true"
      XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: "true"
    networks:
      - es
    depends_on:
      - master01
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

networks:
  es:
    driver: overlay
```

It actually works apart from the fact that my master01,02,03 are created randomly and can be moved around randomly on the 3 nodes meaning that they will replicate their data to the new node when they can't find it after being remade on a new node. 
Over time this means my data exists x3.

I haven't been able to use constraints properly to bind the 3 elastic services to a node each, and i can't really seem to find anything that works when searching.

I've tried using **environment: "constraint:node==node1"** but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all when building using my compose file.

I've searched around and found some examples on how to do it with **docker service create**, but i can't seem to find a functioning syntax.

First time posting here, so if i did something wrong, be gentle please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found a solution myself.

http://embaby.com/blog/using-glusterfs-docker-swarm-cluster/

Gluster might be the perfect solution, i will post results tomorrow if it solves my problem.